# symfony 4 count method with doctrine-orm

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I am a beginner in symfony 4, and I wanted to count the recording of an object, but it does not work.
this is my code

// Function count() in my repository class

```
public function count()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->select('count(d.codeMarche) as count')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

// in my controller class, i called my function count()

```
/**
  * @Route("/", name="home")
  */
public function hom(MarcheDAORepository $repo){
   $count = $repo->count();

    return $this->render('index/home.html.twig', ['nbrDAO'=>$count]);
}
```

i need your help!!

Comment: define *does not work* please. Any error message? What's the result of `var_dump($count);` ?

Comment: ErrorException
Warning: Declaration of App\Repository\MarcheDAORepository::count() should be compatible with Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::count(array $criteria)

Comment: the method `count` is already defined in [EntityRepository](the https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/latest/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.html) class so try to rename as example `countMarche` and see what happen

Comment: Thanks!! it's worked but i have also an exception string(2) "10", number 10 is th numbre of recording

Comment: ok you can use the default count implementation so try to call the count() method of the parent class and should return an integer value

Answer (score 2):

The [count](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/latest/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.html#method_count) method is already defined in the parent class so you can simply omit your implementation and use the default one (that return an int value as the doc suggest) or rename your method if you want to use a custom implementation, as example

```
public function countCodeMarche()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->select('count(d.codeMarche) as count')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

That will return a string and you should cast to int if you need a different type.

Answer (score -3):

You can do that by the following code :

```
public function hom(MarcheDAORepository $repo){
   $items = $repo->findAll();
   $count=count($items);
    return $this->render('index/home.html.twig', ['nbrDAO'=>$count]);
}
```